# create location in GMB , error PIN_DROP_REQUIRED, how to use the UI to provide a pin drop

Tags: google-my-business-api

I am testing on google auth playgound,any please help me out

{
"error": {
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
"code": 400,
"details": [
{
"reason": "PIN_DROP_REQUIRED",
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
"domain": "mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com",
"metadata": {
"field_mask": "storefront_address"
}
}
]
}
}

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, Google will only let you edit an address via the Google Business Profile user interface (and not via the API): https://business.google.com